# CamelContext.removeRouteDefinitions() does not remove direct:// endpoints

Tags: apache-camel

When I remove a route with CamelContext.removeRouteDefinitions(), I cannot add this route again beacause it says `Endpoint direct://something only allows 1 active consumer but you attempted to start a 2nd consumer.`

Is it normal? How can I remove those endpoints from the context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to remove the endpoint as well, there is API on CamelContext to remove endpoints.

Comment: How do you do this?  How do you get the endpoint from a route?  Some code would be helpful.